# swift callback doesn't print

Tags: ios, swift, callback

I try to understand the main concept of callbacks in swift
I have the following code:

```
typealias ImageHandler = (String,NSError?) -> Void

 func PostOnSocialMedia(image:String?){
    println(0)

    Post({(image)->Void in
     println(1)
    })

    println(2)
}

func Post(handler:ImageHandler){
    println(3)
}
```

my code output is 0,3,2 and my question is why doesn't print the number 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not printing 1 because you are passing in a function that is never called.

This:

```
Post({ (image)->Void in
     println(1)
})
```

declares a temporary function (a “closure expression” – a quick easy way to declare anonymous functions, between the `{ }`) that takes an argument of a `(String,NSError?)` pair, and returns nothing.  Then it passes that function into the `Post` function.

But the `Post` function does nothing with it.  For a function to run, it needs to be called.  If you changed your `Post` function like so:

```
func Post(handler:ImageHandler){
    println(3)

    // call the handler that was passed in...
    handler("blah",nil)
}
```

you’ll see it printing a 1.

Note, the `image` argument received by `PostOnSocialMedia` and the `image` argument variable inside the temporary function are two different variables – scoping rules mean the one declared inside the temp function masks the one in the outer scope.  But they are very different (in fact, they’re different types – one is a string, and the other is a 2-tuple of a string and an error).

Try [reading this](http://airspeedvelocity.net/2014/06/11/a-basic-tutorial-on-functions-and-closures-in-swift/) for a short intro on first-order functions and closures in Swift.